# Changing images in Lua

Tags: image, lua, coronasdk

I am making a game in Lua that requires an image to change multiple times. The way I am doing it right now is to display a new image over the old one. This works but it causes a lot of lag. I am wondering if someone knows a way to get rid of the old image and then place the new image in the same location. Thanks guys.

Example of what I'm doing each time something happens:

```
local function checkPlayer1()
    if P1 == 1 then
        player1 = display.newImage("1.png",64,128) --starting
    end

    if P1 == 2 then
        player1 = display.newImage("2.png",64,128)
    end

    if P1 == 3 then
        player1 = display.newImage("3.png",64,128)
    end

    if P1 == 4 then
        player1 = display.newImage("4.png",64,128)
    end

    if P1 == 5 then
        player1 = display.newImage("5.png",64,128) --dead
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing, by the look of it, it's Corona SDK. You can use `player1:removeSelf()` to remove the previous image object before creating a new one. That's assuming `player1` is a global (or a closure) that points to the previous image.

Comment: Just commenting to tell you that you should edit questions to include relevant tags yourself.